# How do Facebook and Google send text messages?

Tags: facebook, sms

I'm interested in how companies like Facebook and Google send text messages, I know you can email a users phone number, but they must do it in another way, what hardware/software do they use to send text messages?

Comment: they do it over http, look into websockets

Comment: @ScottSelby Really? I've played with websockets a little bit (using node.js) I didn't know you could send sms over HTTP. I'll look into it some more, thanks.

Comment: ohhh.. you mean sms , that can be done over smtp

Comment: but facebook and google are going to use http to their apps on the users phone

Comment: @ScottSelby Well I guess I'm looking for whatever way Facebook and Google do it, where it doesn't show an email, but a number instead.

Comment: facebook and google chat don't send an sms , they open in their own apps on the phone

Comment: @ScottSelby No I'm not talking about an app or chat or anything like that, I'm talking about things like verification via phone (where they send you a text message with a code, and you enter it on a website)